# "script stack space quota is exhausted" error with jquery, xml parsing

Tags: javascript, xml

Using jquery, my code parse kml file,
and get information from the xml file.
the code is following:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/getKmlFile',
        data: {fname: "route.kml"},
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'xml',
        complete: function(data, status){
            console.debug("here");
            var startTime = $(data.responseText).find('TimeSpan > begin').text();
            .....
            .....
            $(data.responseText).find('LineString').each(function (index) {
                ....
            }
            ....
    });
```

the problem is, 
firefox make an error log, "script stack space quota is exhausted".
and the execution is exited in this line:

```
var startTime = $(data.responseText).find('TimeSpan > begin').text();
```

I just use jquery default selector, and find xml elements.
That's all what I did.

kml file size is not so big, it's just 1.6Mbyte.

is there any way to avoid this problem?
Using another xml parser?
help me please~~~
: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resloved the problem.

the solution was very simple.

```
complete: function(data, status){    => success: function(data, status){
```

in complete function data.responseText is string not xml object, but, in success function
data is xml object.

following code should be like this,

```
$(data).find("...") ...                not, $(data.responseText).find("...") ...
```

so, less memory and very effecient traversing~

interesting~ ^^;